# iphone flip is zooming in (against my will)

Tags: iphone, mobile, jquery-mobile

I've started working on a mobile page and I've made the css so that the page can expand or contract and look fine. When I rotate the page though, by turning my iphone sideways, instead of resizing as though there is a new screen size (wide), it's zooming in. I have an image on the page and I really don't want it to zoom in, because it pixelates the image. I would rather it resize as though it was a new page.

You can see it here:
http://scclib.com/mobile

Comment: I think I figured it out by adding this meta tag, I haven't tested it on android or ipads, but this at least solves my problem for iphone. 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by adding this meta tag, I haven't tested it on android or ipads, but this at least solves my problem for iphone.